# Grunt Watch isn't working anymore

Tags: gruntjs, watch

I was trying to figure out why my JS wasn't being compiled by grunt, so I edited the gruntfile.js. And then grunt watch stopped. I've tried reverting the file with git and I've npm installed to try to see if that might help... does anyone see a problem with my gruntfile? Or perhaps have another possible solution?

```
 module.exports = function(grunt){
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');

 grunt.initConfig({
 uglify:{
    my_target: {
        files: {
            'js/script.js': ['_/js/*.js']

        }//files
    }//target
},//uglify
compass:{
    dev:{
        options: {
            config:'config.rb'
        }//options
    }//dev
}, //compass
watch: {
    options:{ livereload: true },
    scripts: {
        files: ['_/js/*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify']

    },
    sass: {
        files:['_/sass/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass:dev']
    }//sass

    //scripts
    // html: {
    //  files: ['*.html']
    // } //for auto refresh browser, need script on html as well.
}//watch


  })//initConfig
  grunt.registerTask('default','watch') //run gunt and wait for changes

 }//exports
```

and here are my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies" : {
    "grunt" : "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch" : "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass" : "~1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify" : "~0.9.1",
    "matchdep" : "~0.3.0"
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem with grunt not working     options:{ livereload: true, },  needed a comma after true... anyone have an idea why my scripts are not compiling?

Comment: and now it's working. This is closed... apparently I had a bad call in one of my js files.